# Recommended to use Lingo with Spring?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, remoting, messaging, rpc

I'm going through some examples for how to configure asynchronous JMS messaging with Spring, and the book I'm going through, Spring In Action, 2nd Edition (I know there's a 3rd edition out there), mentions using Lingo (http://lingo.codehaus.org/ for messaged-based RPC asynchronous messaging.

The latest version of Lingo is a couple years old, so I was wondering if there is a newer, better practice to use than Lingo.  Any advice?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would take a look at [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration). Check out the comprehensive documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/spring-integration-reference.html), in particular the section on [JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/spring-integration-reference.html#jms).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll def. look at this.